# Rails Associations: Going from has_many to has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm still new to Rails and am try to figure out how to associate a model with a user as a has_one.

This was set up initially assuming that my users would have many finances. Now, I need to change it so a user has one finance.

**Finance model**:

```
class Finance < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    validates :age, presence: true
    validates :zip, presence: true
end
```

**User model**:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :finances
end
```

When I change  has_many :finances to has_one :finances, my finances controller is throwing an error.

```
class FinancesController < ApplicationController    
  # GET /finances
  # GET /finances.json
  def index
    @finances = Finance.find_all_by_user_id current_user[:id] if current_user
  end

  # GET /finances/new
  def new
    @finance = current_user.finances.build
  end

  # GET /finances/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /finances
  # POST /finances.json
  def create
    @finance = current_user.finances.build(finance_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @finance.save
        format.html { redirect_to @finance, notice: 'Successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @finance }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @finance.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /finances/1
  # PATCH/PUT /finances/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @finance.update(finance_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @finance, notice: 'Successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @finance.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /finances/1
  # DELETE /finances/1.json
  def destroy
    @finance.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to finances_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_finance
      @finance = Finance.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
        @finance = current_user.finances.find_by(id: params[:id])
        redirect_to root_path, notice: "Welcome to TrustRose" if @finance.nil?
    end
end
```

The error comes here:

```
 @finance = current_user.finances.find_by(id: params[:id])
```

**I believe this will need to change, but I am not how to query the database to find the finance associated with the user now that the user only has one.**

Comment: You need to update your routes and change `current_user.finances.find_by(..)` to just `current_user.finance`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `routes.rb`, change `resources :finances` to `resource :finance`

Then, change your `User` model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  has_one :finance
end
```

With the `has_one` association, you can use `@finance = current_user.finance` in your controller

Now, display it in your view using something like:

```
<%= @finance.age %>
```

Hope that helps?

Comment: Would this mean I'd have to rename my existing finances_controller to finance_controller? Changing that in my routes.rb doesn't allow me to edit my finances regularly (/finances/6/edit) anymore

Comment: No, you don't have to, and, should not rename the controller file. Assuming that `finance` should only be edited by current user, you just need to change it with  `/finance/edit`

Comment: /finance/edit gives me: Routing Error
uninitialized constant FinanceController. edit_finance_path  GET  /finance/:id/edit(.:format)  finance#edit

Comment: Check again your routes, have you changed your `routes.rb` correctly? Using `rake routes` you will find a line `edit_finance GET /finance/edit(.:format) finances#edit`. If the routes is correct, it should be fine.

Comment: Still had resources (plural) in there. Got it - thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You problem relates to Active Record Pluralisation of your model names: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Try this:

```
@finance = current_user.finance
```

Comment: Previously in the view to get the Finances associated to the user, I used this line: <% @finances.each do |finance| %>. How would this change with the has_one association?

Comment: You wouldn't intreating over a collection of finances anymore. So what what ever you did inside of the block, i.e <%= finance.attribute_name %>, you just do once. So ditch the .each bit :)